# Cannot implicitly convert string to CBCharacteristic?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

```
    public void GrantLocalUARTCredits()
    {
     if (this.PendingLocalUARTCreditsCount != 0) return;
     this.PendingLocalUARTCreditsCount = this.MaxLocalUARTCreditsCount - 
                       this.LocalUARTCreditsCount;
        Byte[]  byteData = new Byte[1];


        byteData[0] = (Byte)((this.PendingLocalUARTCreditsCount &  0xFF));
        NSData valueData = (NSData.FromArray(byteData));
      Characteristic UartRxCreditsCharacteristic = "00000003-0000-1000-
```

8000-008025000000";(error here)

```
       this.CbPeripheral.WriteValue(valueData, this.UartRxCreditsCharacteristic, CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse);
 }
```

I'm using CoreBluetools in a xamarin C# project and 
get null reference exception with the last line as the CBCharacteristic I think is not defined. At the top of the file I define CBCharacteristic with

`public CBCharacteristic UartRxCreditsCharacteristic {get ; set;}`

and in this file below this I set the uuid with

`public static string UART_RX_CREDITS_UUID = " 00000003-0000-1000-8000-008025000000"`
I can discover,connect and disconnect with the app as it worked with our original device but with this device it requires RX/TX credits to communicate (1 credit for each 20 byte packet max 255 credits). This bit of code is from  the original translated Objective C (to C#) manufacturers code and the error is the WriteValue code line says 'Null reference Exception'((object reference not set to an instance of an object) as I think the Characteristic  can't be found when I run the code. `enter code here`

Not sure how to solve this. Nick

Comment: you are trying to assign a string to a `Characteristic` and it does not know how to convert that.  Where is `Characteristic` defined?

Comment: where is the type Characteristic defined?  iOS uses `CBCharacteristic`, so I have no idea where this "Characteristic" type is coming from

Comment: the VERY FIRST WORD in this post is "Characteristic".  Are you saying that is a typo and that it is actually "CBCharacteristic"?  The TITLE of your post also says "Characteristic", not "CBCharacteristic".

Comment: it is very difficult for people to help you if you cannot accurately describe your problem.  Your post is only three lines and yet contains multiple inaccuracies.  Please edit your post to correct them - if you are not able to do that, I'd suggest that you delete it and repost with accurate code, error messages, etc.  Please read [ask] for guidance on writing a good question.

Comment: Welcome to SO Nick! There is nothing called "Characteristic" in Xamarin.iOS. I think you mean CBCharacteristic. This will probably help you: https://github.com/aspenryd/BLEProject/blob/9bb38d228475072dde0fa6c4bb6ce9019b1136c6/BluetoothLEExplorer.iOS/UI/Screens/Scanner/ServiceDetails/ServiceDetailsScreen.cs

Comment: Hi Saamer, my app worked with our original Bluetooth device but with the new one we need to set rx and TX credits to communicate. I can discover, connect and disconnect already just this setting rx credits is, from the translated objective C (to C#) manufacturers code. Yes I edited my question to say I was using CBCharacteristic. Regards nick

Answer (score 0):

```
    This code does the trick
    internal void Connect(CBPeripheral peripheral)
    {



        peripheral.DiscoveredService += (sender, e) =>
         {
             if (peripheral.Services == null) { return; }
             foreach (var s in peripheral.Services)
             //  var s in peripheral.Services
             {
                 //if (s.UUID.ToString().Contains("0000f100"))
                 if (s.UUID.ToString().Contains("fefb"))
                 //s = s.UUID.ToString();
                 {
                     service = s;
                     peripheral.DiscoverCharacteristics(service);
                 };
             }
         };

        peripheral.DiscoveredCharacteristic += (sender, e) =>
        {
            foreach (var c in service.Characteristics)
            {
                if (c.UUID.ToString() == (TIO_UART_RX_UUID))
                {
                    UartRxCharacteristic = c;
                }
            }


            foreach (var c in service.Characteristics)
            {

                if (c.UUID.ToString() == (TIO_UART_RX_CREDITS_UUID)) 

                {
                    UartRxCreditsCharacteristic = c;
                }
            }

            foreach (var c in service.Characteristics)
            {

                if (c.UUID.ToString() == (TIO_UART_TX_CREDITS_UUID))
                {
                    UartTxCreditsCharacteristic = c;
                    peripheral.SetNotifyValue(true, c);
                }
            }
            foreach (var c in service.Characteristics)
            {
                if (c.UUID.ToString() == (TIO_UART_TX_UUID))
               // {
```